# Generalized eigenspace formula

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, generalized-eigenvector

I'm trying to figure out the very last sentence of the proof of this theorem, and I don't understand why what they're saying is true.

Theorem: Let $V$ be an $F$ vector space with $\dim_{F} V=n$ and $T:V \longrightarrow V$ linear with characteristic polynomial $f_T$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.  Then if $f_T$ splits in $F[X]$ and the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ is $m$, then:

1. $\dim_{F} K_{\lambda}(T) \leq m$ where $K_{\lambda}(T)$ is the generalized eigenspace of $T$ for $\lambda$.
2. $N((T-\lambda I)^m) = K_{\lambda}(T)$.

I follow everything up until showing $K_{\lambda}(T) \subset N((T-\lambda I)^m)$.  The proof given just says 'it follows immediately by the choice of $m$.'  But I don't see how it follows at all.  If $x \in K_{\lambda}(T)$, then there exists some $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(T-\lambda I)^p(x) = 0$, but I don't see why the dimension of $K_{\lambda}(T)$ being bounded above by $m$ proves this containment.

Comment: You can prove 2 directly: with $\dim K_\lambda(T) = m'\leq m$ and $S:= T-\lambda I$ write $V= \ker S^n \oplus \text{image } S^n$, then build a basis $\mathbf B$ reflecting that direct sum so $S\mathbf B=\mathbf BA$ where $A$ is block diagonal and its leading block, $A_1$ is $m'\times m'$, i.e. the first $m'$ vectors of $\mathbf B$ form a basis for $K_\lambda(T)$. Cayley Hamilton tells you $A_1$ raised to the mth power is zero, i.e. $\ker S^{m}= K_\lambda(T)$ since the other factors of the char poly applied to $A_1$ result in invertible matrices.

Comment: technically I took for granted at the end that $m'=m$ since $m'\lt m \implies \det\big(A_2\big)=0$ but $S$ is injective on $\text{image } S^n$